# Help with retopo, verts snapping to wrong face

Tags: snapping, shrinkwrap

[image]

So this is my first retopo and I'm having an issue with snapping.  I'm not able to take an edge loop and pull it up and down a limb (this is the leg) without all the verts snapping to the side of the object facing the viewport.  Currently my settings are: snap to face with project onto self and project individual elements enabled, and with the shrinkwrap modifier I'm using nearest surface and on surface.

It seems to want to snap to whatever's closest to the viewport rather than whatever's closest to the actual vert. Example if I'm working on a part of the torso and the wrist is close to the viewport it will snap all the way to the wrist rather than the point on the torso that's much closer.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: I'm may be wrong but I'm not sure it can work differently, if you select all the vertices it will snap to the closest face(s) you see, not to the closest face(s) of each vertex

Comment: Dang really?  So you pretty much have to extrude one edge at a time when you go down an arm or leg?  That seems so counter-intuitive but I guess that's why you start with very large polys X(  thank you for your response!